# Summarise does not include all data

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have few different tables and I want to put it into one table.
Table '**Storename**' and '**Country mapping**' are tables to provide more details information.
while '**Sales Data**' are the main data table.

I found out once I summarize everything into one table (**Table1**),
not all the data from '**Sales Data**' shows up in **Table1**.
Below is the code that I used.

```
Table1 =
VAR UserTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        'Sales DATA',
        "Store", RELATED ( 'Storename'[Store info] ),
        "Country", RELATED ( 'Country Mapping'[Country Code] ),
        "district", 'Sales DATA'[district],
        "Region Name", RELATED ( 'Country Mapping'[Region] )
    )
RETURN
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table1,
        [Store],
        [Country],
        [district],
        [Region Name],
        'Sales DATA'[Date],
        'Sales DATA'[Category],
        'Sales DATA'[Product],
        'Sales DATA'[Store Code],
        'Sales DATA'[Qty Sold],
        'Sales DATA'[Product cost],
        'Sales DATA'[Profit]
    )
```

Comment: can you outline what is missing? and show an example

Comment: SUMMARIZE groups the data so that duplicates will be consolidated into unique row, maybe that is what is confusing you?

Comment: From the original 'Sales data', [qty sold],[product cost],[profit] has a bigger amount, but once it's summarize, the amount is lower. I make sure there's no blank in every column, but still there's no change.